# Should folds in k-fold CV actually be representative?

Tags: cross-validation, optimization, hyperparameter, representative

I have read somewhere that the *k* of the *k*-fold CV should be picked in such a manner as to have representative validation sets (folds). This seems to me to be contradictory since the *leave-one-out* CV has only one sample as a fold, which clearly can't be representative of the dataset (I refer to one fold only, the whole process is perfectly fine as it is averaged). Furthermore, LOOCV is less biased than the *k*-fold CV due to it practically using the whole dataset for model fitting, albeit more expensive computationally. Of course, a smaller fold usually also implies a larger variance in the error, but this does not seem relevant in this instance.

Should each fold actually be representative?

Comment: What do you mean by representative? That each fold should have similarly distributed data? If so then this is usually a good idea. You may also be interested in stratified CV.

Comment: Yes, representative of the underlying distribution. Similarly distributed to the rest of the dataset, in more practical terms. Why is it usually a good idea and at the same time LOOCV works fine, and it clearly doesn't have a representative fold (it's just one sample)? Stratified CV seems to be more concerned with unbalanced classification problems and does not seem to address my question, at least I think so.

Comment: You got that wrong, LOOCV trains on all except one unit, and tests on the left out unit, so LOOCV is very representative (for training the model, which is what the main concern is, prediction will be done by all the other similarly trained models and should reflect the final model predictions).

Comment: My question is why should one fold/subsample (which is the validation set in one iteration of k-fold CV) be representative, not why the training set should be representative: that part is quite clear. I understand how LOOCV works.

Comment: “Of course, a larger fold usually implies a smaller variance in the error, but this doesn't seem relevant in most cases.”—Why not, though? When one has to consider costs (like time or computational budget), the standard CV becomes more attractive because of the lower variance. You can’t do LOOCV with all data points in a 3 million sample, billion-parameter machine translation model, for instance.

Comment: A classic dataset has mobile phone accelerometer data with the aim of predicting whether somebody is sitting, standing, walking up, walking down or walking level, with many readings for several individuals.  If the aim is to make good predictions for future users rather than for existing users, there is an argument this is best done in the train-validate-test paradigm by putting all the data for some individuals in the test set, and the CV folds to be individuals, rather than other representative selections of the observations.  You might say this approach is not representative of all the data

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy You're right and I agree with you. My wording could have been better, I wanted to say that it does not seem to be relevant when assessing models for the purpose of model selection, given that we have the resources to actually perform LOOCV. However, this is not my main point. What I am interested in is why should a fold be representative in k-fold CV if we are averaging the fold scores anyway, a demonstration of which is precisely the LOOCV (which clearly doesn't have representative folds).

Comment: @Henry I see, this is an interesting argument, but once again, it's a specific use case. I'm trying to get a general answer. Moreover, for your example, we could say that the folds indeed are representative, not of our data per se, but of our target.

Comment: What do you mean by 'representative'? Why is n-fold/leave-one-out cross validation not representative? (or at least you seem to suggest this with *"This seems to me to be contradictory since the leave-one-out CV is..."*)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus LOOCV has unrepresentative folds in the sense that the one fold that is used for validation in one of the n iterations (which is just one sample), cannot possibly be representative of our dataset. The question is therefore why should a fold in k-fold CV be representative (the same kind of representative) if the one in LOOCV is clearly not?

Comment: @bob_cart but LOOCV is done with n different folds which makes it representative right? One uses an average over the k folds. It is the k folds as a whole that need to be representative and single fold doesn't need to be.

Comment: Could you refer to a place where you have read that the folds need to be 'representative'.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Yeah, I agree with your comment about LOOCV. I read it [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/) (the 'configuration of k' section). I think I've read it in other places as well, but I could be wrong and I could've misinterpreted the link I sent. That's why I posted the question, to get my facts straight. Maybe the author was referring to the training set, and the validation (test) set in terms of unbalanced datasets and the stratified CV?

Comment: @bob_cart stratified CV is indeed a good example of requiring a 'representative' fold (not really requiring but it will be more efficient). But this is more about picking the folds than about picking the number $k$. Possibly they are referring to problems that might occur when data is correlated. In such case LOOCV might not work so well because training data is correlated with your test data (the left out data point is not a good representation of an independent piece of data). In such a case you probably want a larger piece/fold of data to be left out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a reasonable question but it might be conflating 2 things.

1. Should $k$ be chosen to make [something] representative?
2. Should the-way-we-assign-data-to-each-fold be chosen to make [something] representative?

### 1) Choice of $k$

In a comment the OP says "I read it [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/) (the 'configuration of k' section)..."
And in that linked blog post, that blog's author writes:

> Representative: The value for k is chosen such that each train/test group of data samples is large enough to be statistically representative of the broader dataset.

Rather than being representative of the *broader dataset*, it's often more useful to think about being representative of the *population* from which the dataset came.

That's because cross validation is less suited to answering "How well would this model perform on new data if I fit it to *this* dataset?" (conditional test error), and better suited to answering "How well does this model tend to perform on new data after being fit to *datasets like this one*?" (expected test error)
See for instance Section 7.12 of *The Elements of Statistical Learning* [(Hastie et al., 2nd ed)](https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/), or the preprint "Cross-validation: what does it estimate and how well does it do it?" [(Bates et al., 2021)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.00673).

Of course, often we still want to use the CV estimates to choose a model for *our* dataset. It's just helpful to realize that they are one step removed from directly answering that question.

For the moment let's just talk about the case when the original dataset was an iid sample from the population. No temporal correlation, group-hierarchical structure, etc.

In that spirit, if you choose $k=n$ and use LOOCV, each CV training set will be almost the same size as your full dataset. So CV will be "representative" in that it's trying to measure your model's expected performance when trained on datasets of (nearly) the same size as your full dataset. If that is indeed your goal, LOOCV is "representative" in that model performance estimates should be nearly unbiased.

By contrast, smaller $k$ such as $k=5$ might be "less representative" in that CV will try to measure your model's expected performance when trained on datasets smaller than the one you really have. Imagine you could get a plot of true expected model performance vs sample size. If this "learning curve" is still steep at sample size $n*4/5$, you'll get a pessimistic view of how well your model would tend to perform on samples of size $n$.

That's all in terms of repeated sampling: if you repeated the process of [collect an entirely new dataset of size $n$ and run CV] many times, LOOCV should have smaller bias than other values of $k$. But the standard story is that there's a bias-variance tradeoff, and LOOCV may have higher variance than others. So we often choose a moderate value like $k=10$ and hope that the learning curve is flat enough for samples of size $n*9/10$ to be "representative" but not too variable across repeated sampling.

In any case, in a complete run of $k$-fold CV (using all the folds), every observation will be in a test fold exactly once. Different values of $k$ will make those test cases more or less correlated with other observations (affecting the variance over repeated sampling)---but won't change the total number of test cases. However, if you're only doing a *single* train/test split, then yes, you should try to get enough data in both the training set (so you can afford to fit realistically/usefully complex models) and in the test set (so you can evaluate them with enough precision to distinguish better models from worse ones).

### 2) Choice of how to assign data to each fold

The OP also writes:

> ...should be picked in such a manner as to have representative validation sets (folds). This seems to me to be contradictory since the leave-one-out CV has only one sample as a fold, which clearly can't be representative of the dataset...

That's okay. If the dataset is iid from the population, any one test case is a "representative" sample ($n=1$) of that population. And the set of all LOOCV test cases *across folds* is representative of the population too.

This relates to a common misconception:
**Shouldn't we try to make each fold look as similar to the full dataset as possible?**
and I would answer:
**No.** In the spirit of conditional vs expected test error, **the way each fold is *sampled* should be representative of how the full dataset was sampled.**
Reference: "K-fold cross-validation for complex sample surveys" [(Wieczorek et al., 2022)](https://doi.org/10.1002/sta4.454).

This will help CV to estimate "How well is this model expected to perform on datasets *collected the same way as this one*?" Otherwise, if CV ignores something important about your sampling design, it will be a much less useful approximation to "How well might this model work on *my* full dataset?"

So for instance, CV for time-series data generally keeps blocks of temporally-consecutive observations together, and also ensures that we train on earlier data and test on later data. If we formed folds randomly instead, the training data might look "more representative" of the full dataset---but it wouldn't be useful for assessing our ability to make forecasts.
Reference: "Cross-validation strategies for data with temporal, spatial, hierarchical, or phylogenetic structure" [(Roberts et al., 2016)](https://doi.org/10.1111/ecog.02881).

Likewise, in CV for grouped data (like in @Henry's comment), generally we want to keep entire groups together when making CV folds. If we have several observations for each subject in a study, folds should be formed subject-by-subject since this is how we sampled the data. (So $k$-fold would put $n/k$ subjects in each fold, and LOOCV would put one subject in each fold.) If the training and test sets have different subjects, this lets us honestly evaluate how well we'd make predictions for future subjects not yet in the dataset.
Reference: "The need to approximate the use-case in clinical machine learning" [(Saeb et al., 2017)](https://doi.org/10.1093/gigascience/gix019).

Finally, since stratified CV came up in the comments: I would not usually do stratified CV unless the original data collection really was stratified. Otherwise CV may be over-optimistic. It will be estimating "this model's performance when trained on stratified data," whereas you actually want an estimate "...when trained on iid data" or whatever.
(The exception of course is a classification problem with a rare outcome category: then you might be forced to stratify on the response, because otherwise you might never see that outcome in some training sets.)

Comment: The research I have done after posting the question confirms what you wrote here, and I agree with you. I have read conflicting opinions about LOOCV having higher variance, but I suppose that is why you wrote that it is "the standard story". The example with temporal data is great and something I have actually come by recently. Thanks a lot for providing a thorough answer!

Comment: @bob_cart Thank you very much! And yes, you noticed my careful word choice about the "standard story" :)  Thanks for asking a good question!

Answer (score 0):

The book [*The Elements of Statistical Learning*](https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/) considers *leave-one-out* cross-validation a form of *k*-fold cross-validation, and in this version the validation set of each fold consists of only a single example, and can for that reason not be said to be representative of the dataset. So no, the folds in *k*-fold cross-validation do not have to have representative validation sets.

Comment: Unless $N$ is very large (in some cases $> 20000$ for binary Y, a single 10-fold CV will be imprecise/unstable.  That’s why it’s best to repeat the whole process 50-100 times, in which case the representativeness issue resolves itself.

Comment: k-fold cross-validation *can* have unrepresentative validation sets, but that doesn't answer the question whether or not it *should* have representative validation sets.